# "these are/it is" "too much/too many" macaroni

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

You've got macaroni spilt all over your house. Which one would be a correct version?

1. These are too much macaroni.
2. These are too many macaroni.
3. It's too much macaroni.

Comment: None of the above. If it fell off my plate then obviously *there is not enough macaroni*.

Comment: Quite unhelpful.

Comment: Well you have to read my comment more carefully. I'm not gong to just give it away.

Comment: This is not even remotely a duplicate! The other question is entirely and only about whether you add an *s* to the end of *macaroni* and related words. This question doesn't ask about that at all! Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers one and two are not grammatical. Keep in mind that macaroni is a singular term requiring a singular verb. You may wish to write, "There is too much macaroni."

Comment: Thank you. Fred. I meant there is for #3. And I just heard #2 on tv, and didn't expect they would say thing ungrammatical.

Comment: _Macaroni_ is **not** generally a singular term. It is a mass noun taking a singular verb. It is actually a plural-form loan-word. And the anglicised plural _macaronis_ of the countified version has been used for 'types of', like _coffees_ and _rices_.

Comment: "There are too many pieces of macaroni"